# Flask initialisation for unit test and app

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a Flask application which I'd like to run some unit tests on. To do so, I create a new Flask object, initialise blueprints, SQLA and a few other packages and execute the test case.

However, I've noticed that some endpoints on the test flask object are missing, which made me wonder about the general way of how initialisation is handled in flask.

Taking a minimal example, an endpoint would be created like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If I was to create a new Flask object somewhere in my testcase's setUp method, it would most certainly not contain a route '/' as this route was created from another flask object (the one from the file above). So my question is: How should a test case be written and how is the initialisation meant to work in general? Somewhere I read that one should avoid initialisation at import (i.e. on a module level), but this seems to be impossible if annotations are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create a new `Flask` object in your test cases. You *import your existing `app` instead*.

In many project setups you already added all your extensions to that `app`. In many of mine I have a factory method that'll take a configuration object and returns the fully initialized `app` object for me; I use this to create a base test case:

```
import unittest

import project


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = True
    CACHE_NO_NULL_WARNING = True  # silence Flask-Cache warning
    SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'


class ProjectCoreViewCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Base test case for the Project core app"""

    def setUp(self, **kwargs):
        config = Config()
        config.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        app = project.create_app(config)
        self.app = app.test_client()
```

and any tests can then use `self.app` as the test client in all tests.

This is a base test case, you'd inherit from it; the `setUp()` method allows for additional configuration to be set, by passing in keyword arguments to a `super()` call:

```
class ConcreteTestCase(ProjectCoreViewCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(ConcreteTestCase, self).setUp(
            SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='your_test_specific_connection_uri',
        )
```

Comment: Ok. Assuming I do the import, how would I handle SQLA initialisation with Flask-SQLAlchemy. `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` can only be called once. I have different databases to test with and would need to initialise SQLA multiple times...

Comment: And if you use a factory method in your app (not the test case), how do you use it together with say the `@app.route('/')` annotation?

Comment: @orange: do you have multiple *models* (and applications) or multiple database implementations (sqlite, MySQL, etc.)? The former means you need to separate out your tests; the latter is a variation of configuration.

Comment: @orange: I create `app = Flask()` as a global, use the `@app.route()` decorator (which is executed on importing that module) and the factory only applies blueprints, extensions and additional configuration.

Comment: I also use a global `app` instance. Re the database, I use the same models and db implementations, but different databases (all postgres) to test different scenarios (i.e. they have different content). I guess it could be done with a separate configuration. The problem is just that the initialisation is already done once the `setUp` of the test case, in which I could change the config, is called.

Comment: In your above example using the factory method `app = project.create_app(config)`, you will have the same issues I described in my post: Some endpoints won't be available, as the `app` instance you create in `create_app` is different to the ones used for the route annotation elsewhere in your application `@app.route()`. How do you get around this problem?

Comment: @orange: This is a base testcase; if you inherit from it, you can set additional config by passing in keywords to the `setUp` method. I should have made this explicit before.

Comment: If you call `setUp` multiple times, which is what happens if you have more than 1 test case, you'd get an exception (`AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late.
To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.`) at `SQLAlchemy(app)` (which is what happens in your `project.create_app(config)` call).

Comment: ... How do you get around this? Your (hypothetical?) code doesn't seem to prevent this exception from being raised.

Comment: @orange: `setUp()` is called once per test *by the test runner*. Don't call it from your tests. Have your **test case** override it, call the original with `super()`, but then **don't call it again in your test method**.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. We're on the same page. I meant once per test (method), not once per test case, and that's exactly the problem. The test runner calls it multiple times, i.e. once before every test (using the same global `app` object) which causes the above exception.

Comment: @orange: I cannot reproduce this; not with the `nose` testrunner, nor with the standard `unittest.main()` runner. Then again, that exception is only thrown when `DEBUG` is set to `True`, while my example sets this to `False` instead.

Comment: Right, that must be what makes the difference. Thanks for getting to the bottom of this.